# SQL. Есть 2 таблицы, clients и client_contacts, каким образом их можно объединить по колонке name и обновить значения в таблице clients?

Tags: mysql

нужно перенести данные из client_contacts в clients.  Есть 2 таблицы, clients и client_contacts, каким образом их можно объединить по колонке name и обновить значения в таблице clients?

[image: Таблица client_contacts]

[image: Таблица clients]

Comment: *объединить по колонке name* А значение в этом поле по каждой из таблиц - уникально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

соединяют таблицы  с помощью оператора `join`, обновляют с помощью `update`

```
UPDATE clients 
INNER JOIN clients_contacts AS cc ON (clients.name = cc.name)
SET clients.skype = cc.skype,
    clients.xxx = cc.yyy, ...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, работает)